# Error al guardar un json en bbd mysql phpmyadmin en java

Tags: java, mysql, json

Estoy teniendo problemas para guardar un json en la bbdd de mysql de phpmyadmin.

Este seria mi json, lo he guardado directamente desde la request de un formulario

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, String[]> datosRequest = request.getParameterMap();
String json = gson.toJson(datosRequest);

{"modo":["generarPartido"],"idPartido":["1414"],"idEquipoLocal":["1"],"golesEquipoLocal":["3"],"golesEquipoVisitante":["2"],"idEquipoVisitante":["4"],"chkjuegaJugLocal_1":["on"],"golesJugLocal_1":["3"],"chkjuegaJugVisitante_37":["on"],"golesJugVisitante_37":["2"],"btnGenerarResultado":["Nuevo resultado"]}
```

y este es el error que me da

```
UPDATE partidos_prueba SET golesLocal=3, golesVisitante=2, jugadores='{"modo":["generarPartido"],"idPartido":["1414"],"idEquipoLocal":["1"],"golesEquipoLocal":["3"],"golesEquipoVisitante":["2"],"idEquipoVisitante":["4"],"chkjuegaJugLocal_1":["on"],"golesJugLocal_1":["3"],"chkjuegaJugVisitante_37":["on"],"golesJugVisitante_37":["2"],"btnGenerarResultado":["Nuevo resultado"]} 
WHERE idPartido=1414;
```

Se ha producido un error de tipo SQL.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
> ''{"modo":["generarPartido"],"idPartido":["1414"],"idEquipoLocal":["1"],"golesEqu'
> at line 1`

Os he pegado también la sentencia sql.

PD: querria eliminar del json todos los corchetes y los keys, modo y btnGenerarResultado, he probado utilizando el datosRequest.remove("btnGenerarResultado") pero me falla.
Gracias. Un saludo

Comment: PD: el campo en la bdd donde quiero guardar el json, es tipo text

Comment: phpmyadmin es solo un programa que se conecta a mysql. No tiene nada que ver con la interacción entre java y mysql.

Comment: Y no muestras el código que usas para hacer el update.

Comment: buenas, el update lo tengo puesto en la pregunrta, solo que no me lo ha cogido como codigo, esta justo donde pongo el error:

`UPDATE partidos_prueba SET golesLocal=3, golesVisitante=2, jugadores='{"modo":["generarPartido"],"idPartido":["1414"],"idEquipoLocal":["1"],"golesEquipoLocal":["3"],"golesEquipoVisitante":["2"],"idEquipoVisitante":["4"],"chkjuegaJugLocal_1":["on"],"golesJugLocal_1":["3"],"chkjuegaJugVisitante_37":["on"],"golesJugVisitante_37":["2"],"btnGenerarResultado":["Nuevo resultado"]} WHERE idPartido=1414;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si el código que pegaste es fiel a lo que tiene tu código, te falta cerrar la comilla simple al final del código:

```
... btnGenerarResultado":["Nuevo resultado"]}' WHERE idPartido=1414;
```

Comment: Gracias, me di cuenta mas tarde al probar de otra manera.